# Abrir una página en una nueva pestaña angular

Tags: html, angular

Hola estoy realizando una web, en la cual hay links que quiero abrir en otra pestaña, sin embargo la etiqueta `target = "_blank"` no funciona.

Éste es un ejemplo de la ruta que deseo que se abra en otra pestaña:

```
<a class="navf" 
   (click)="this.router.navigate(['/contactanos'],{fragment: 'ayudaDiv'})"  
   target="_blank">
```

Como puedo hacer para que se abra externamente, utilicé el atributo `target` en `[]` y tampoco funcionó `[target]="'_blank'"`.

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas mezclando dos maneras diferentes de navegar en Angular.

Una es usando el `Router` programáticamente, y el otro es usando el atributo `routerLink`.

Hasta donde yo tengo sabido no hay manera fácil de abrir una nueva pestaña con `Router`.

Pero sí se puede con `routerLink` facilmente:

```
<a class="navf" 
  [routerLink]="['contactanos']" fragment="ayudaDiv"  
  target="_blank">Contacto con atributo routerLink</a>
```

Como ves, se tiene que la parte de `fragment` se agrega también como un atributo.

Te dejo un enlace al [StackBlitz funcionando](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbimh5) con un ejemplo del `Router` programático que no funciona.